# Show active menu item

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

i've a problem and don't know how solve it. 
I need to display the dropdown menu of the current active menu. 
I have the following code:

```
Class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
$id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
  $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
}
return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}

function start_lvl( &$output , $depth = 0 , $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"v-dropdown \">\n";
}



     function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0)
  {
       global $wp_query;
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

       $class_names = $value = '';

       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );

       $class_names = ' '. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '';


       $output .= $indent . '<li >';
       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
       $prepend='';

       $append = '';
       $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';


        $item_output = $args->before;

        if ( $args->has_children ) {
            $append="&nbsp;&#9662;";
                 $item_output .= '<a class="dropdown" data-hover="&nbsp">';
                 $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        } else {
                 $item_output .= '<a class="'.esc_attr( $class_names ).'" '. $attributes .' data-hover="&nbsp'.preg_replace('&nbsp;', $item->title).$append.'" >';
                 $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        }


        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );


        }
```

}

The website is this: http://fidesconsulta.ch/new_site

I need to show the ul class="v-dropdown" when the sub-menu is active. 
Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi could you explain better what you need? Is it to have the services submenu (tax / corporate etc) open when you're in one of these pages? If yes I recommend you to organize these pages according to the wordpress structure, i.e. have Services as pages and Tax, Corporate etc as subpages. Then you can use the handy class css tags added automatically bu wordpress, indicating the parent active page and the current active page (such as current-menu-item, current_page_item etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

You could swap your `<header class="relative">` for this:

```
<header class="relative <?php if ( $post->post_parent == '47' ) { ?>show-menu<?php } ?>" >
```

Replace the parent page ID where the '47' is. That is for if you have these pages set up with a parent id.

If not, you could do it this way, using the same `<header class="relative">` setup.

```
<header class="relative <?php if ( is_page('services') || is_page('corporate-advisory') || is_page('audit-and-accounting') || is_page ('international-orientation-for-smi')) { ?>show-menu<?php } ?>" >
```

Then just add a css class like this in your css:

```
.show-menu ul li:nth-of-type(3) .v-dropdown {display: block; }
```

I set up a test locally, and I think either method will probably work for you. Let me know if I need to clarify.

**Edit:** I've added a psuedo-class in the css to target the first instance of '.v-dropdown' so that only the first menu opens.

**Edit 2:** I have updated the answer to reflect the correct css which helped AnmA solve the problem.

Comment: First: sorry for my bad english. 
Second: that's what I was looking for, but not working properly, because the "dropdown-v" class is applied to every sub-menu like the language's flags. 
To example: when i go on http://fidesconsulta.ch/new_site/corporate-advisory/ every menu-parent are opened.
So, how i can add the "show-menu" class, only to current active parent-menu?  Thank again

Comment: i'm not an expert of php, and i don't know how to do, but can i add the same if statement added to "header" class, in this portion of code?

`function start_lvl( &$output , $depth = 0 , $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"v-dropdown \">\n";
}`

this code is located in function.php.

Comment: I see the issue, sorry, I didn't notice the second dropdown had the same class name. We just need to adjust the css to fix the issue. I'll edit my answer above to correct it. Please apply it and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks a lot, your advice has opened my mind. I didn't know this selector, but after your answer, i studied and i found a solution. 
Your answer not work correctly. The menu remain open, but with this code the menu working correctly :
`.show-menu ul li:nth-of-type(3) .v-dropdown {display: block; }`

Thanks again.